# Is there an rc file (-like option) for jVi in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, rc, jvi

I'm using Netbeans 12 with jVi 1.6.5 on Ubuntu Linux 18.04. Every time I open a new source file in an editor window, I must enter the `:set nu` command manually to enable line numbers in jVi.

Is there a way to automate the latter? I can't find anything about an rc file for jVi, and in NBs `Tools -> Options - >jVi Config` menu I cannot find anything that appears related.

Extensive Googling fails to lead to enlightenment. Am I overlooking something? Can this be set, and if so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `Tools > Options > jViConfig > Windows > 'number' 'nu'`